# h1:nth-child(even) applies property to all h1 elements, instead to even only

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I got the following:

```
<section id="work">
<div class="project">
<h1>something</h1>
<h2>something</h2>
</div>
<div class="project">
<h1>something</h1>
<h2>something</h2>
</div>
<div class="project">
<h1>something</h1>
<h2>something</h2>
</div>
<div class="project">
<h1>something</h1>
<h2>something</h2>
</div>
</section>
```

What I want to do, is to change font size property for every second h1 header. I thought section#work .project h1:nth-child(even) would work, but this changes font size for all h1 headers. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it this that you want to achieve?
https://fiddle.jshell.net/143fvztm/1/

```
div.project:nth-child(even) h1 {
    font-size:36px;
}
```